# ng2-admin: How to use use tables components in Dashboard?

Tags: angular, module, components, ng-admin

I installed this awesome ng2-admin project, it works fine. As I'm new to angular, for experiment I want to used table in one of the dashboard.html div (customizing dashboard page).
I tried, importing TablesModule in DashboardModule, but it did not work.
Please look for project structure here 
https://akveo.github.io/ng2-admin/articles/012-project-structure/
and also source code from
https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin

Any help regarding using tables components in dashboard will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Looks like everything I was doing correct, just missing removing url router from tabled.modules
I commented out following code
//import { routing } from './tables.routing';
  ],
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    //routing'
....
]
and finally removed <router-outlet></router-outlet> from template.
@Component({
  selector: 'tables',
  template: ``
})
```